# Confusion between statically determinate and indeterminate beams

Tags: classical-mechanics, experimental-physics, material-science, solid-mechanics, structural-beam

Why is it that statically determinate beams can take some degree of misfits without any generation of strains or stress, but not statically indeterminate beams?

Comment: What do you mean by “misfits”?

Comment: @BobD misfits in this context would mean not being of the exact dimension they are expected to be, the rim of cart wheels is a relevant example that comes to mind.
Since it's heated up and then slid over the wooden frame.